# Remove certain characters in JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string: `http://www.foo.com/#bar`

How would I go about removing everything before, and including, `#` so I'm only left with `bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use split:

```
var myBar = "http://www.foo.com/#bar".split("#")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

IF the location was LOADED you can do:

`window.location.hash.slice(1)`

`window.location` is an object with a bunch of useful stuff in it like the current security mode (http/s, domain, subdomain, etc.). The hash property contains everything starting with `#`. Slice is a method of both `String` and `Array`, allowing your to start at X and optionally end at Y. (so slice(1) is the same as "start after first and go until the end).

However, the hash property will not show what was typed into the location bar before a pageload. The location property of `window` refers to load location of the document, not the arbitrary things typed into the browser bar without the user submitting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the hash from the URL location.hash will return it.( It is possible to have a URL with more then one #)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp